# how check if CurrentUser is member of group AD?

Tags: sharepoint

This code is not suitable:

```
web.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(web.Groups["Namegruop"].ID);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to distinguish between *AD security group* membership and *SharePoint group* membership.

In order to check AD security membership you can use [`System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kc03hk7.aspx). You do not need to use the SharePoint API:

```
using(WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
{
  WindowsPrincipal p = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
  if (p.IsInRole("DOMAIN\\GroupName")) // Alternative overloads with SecurityIdentifier available
  {
    // ...
  } 
}
```

To check if the current user is member of a SharePoint group you can use the SharePoint API:

```
SPWeb web = // ...
SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups["GroupName"];
if (group.ContainsCurrentUser)
{
  // ...
}
```